# Moving buttons at desired locations

Tags: android

I have this problem: I want to put some Buttons at a certain locations, for example at the four squares of the screen (resolved) and I also want them to become red when clicking on each one, at exactly those locations (not resolved yet).

This is the main xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the main java:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
    btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(listen);
    layout.addView(btnTag);
}

 private View.OnClickListener listen = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if (pressed != null) {
          Button button1 = (Button) pressed;
          button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
       }
       Button button2 = (Button) view;
       GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
       drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
       drawable.setStroke(8, Color.RED);
       button2.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
       pressed = view;
    }
```

Comment: you want all them to become red or the particular one clicked?

Comment: any particular of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onCreate set up your buttons:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(listen);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    two.setOnClickListener(listen);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    three.setOnClickListener(listen);
    Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    four.setOnClickListener(listen);
```

and finally create your listener for all 4 of the buttons:

```
private View.OnClickListener listen = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(8, Color.RED);

        Button button = (Button) view;  
        button.setBackground(drawable);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's useful although all the buttons become red when clicking one.

Comment: I thought this is what you want. If not let me know.

Comment: No, it was that only the botton clicked became red.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you give those buttons IDs, then you can change the color of them when you click it.

So if you tap on buttonID, do your logic and then change the color to buttonID.

```
// If you're in an activity:
buttonID.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Add the color red to your color xml.

this can go inside of your onCreate. the buttonOne and buttonTwo at the IDs to the buttons in your XML.
This is the most BASIC way to do it. There are more ways, you can see those answers here too.

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //logic here
            }
        });

buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //logic here
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is that I have four diferent IDs for the Buttons and they are in the xml

Comment: thats fine... u can have 500 buttons, with 500 different IDs. dont over think this. if you click button with ID 'one' then that code will run, and nothienr else. as long as you are doing onClickListeners

Comment: How can the actiivity know the Button clicked if there are 4 different IDs in xml, according each Button?

Comment: you are answering your question. by the ID. ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you have a listener changing something is relatively easy. You do not need to implement different methods or check every button one by one. Since `Button` is a View as well, do the following pseudo-code.

```
// You need this if part, if you have other views that having the same listener. 
// Otherwise, you do not need this if check.
if(is Clicked View is Button) {
    // Now here, take the clicked view, which we know it is a button and change its colour.
}
```

By the way, the code above will be inside the overridden method `onClick`.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I am adding a small chunk of code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Checking if the clicked View is a Button or not.
    if(view instanceof Button) {

        // view.getId() returns an integer.
        Button clickedButton = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());

        // Now, change the button's colour.
        clickedButton.setBackground(........);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: I edited the answer, please check the edited part, maybe it helps. I also added comments as well, but if you do not understand the logic, please let me know. @F.Alvarado

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your EDIT, but with it the program doesn't get the button.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the program doesn't get the button"_? @F.Alvarado

Comment: It meant that  the buttons din't become red when clicking on each one, bit it's already solved.

Comment: It will actually, do not forget to initialize your buttons. We have the same solutions. However, I am doing a small check if the clicked `View` is a `Button` or not. Learn and use this type of coding. Maybe you will add different views in the future. Then the solution you picked will not work. @F.Alvarado

Answer (score 0):

If you were created Buttons in the layout then why are you adding it dynamically.
If you are using layout then inflate these buttons using "findViewById()". And when user will click perform the action to that or all buttons.

```
one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

But if you are using dynamic button creation then store all 4 button id's which you are creating. Then perform something like this.

```
buttonId[index].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your main class implement to View.OnclickListener

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

                 private void setUpViews() {
                        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
                        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
                        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
                        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
                    }}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view instance of Button){
            button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
                 }
         }
 }
```